# Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 <xyz@xyz.com>: Relay access denied

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

I was working on VS 2013 Ultimate Update 3 and running my application on IIS Express ("http://localhost:2689/"). My Application use to send email. Everything was working fine but for some reason I had to Install VS 2013 Ultimate Update 2 and since then email functionality is not working. I had installed VS 2013 Ultimate Update 3 again But still email is not working. I have also deployed the same code on my release server and emails are working fine but not on my local IIS Express in Visual Studio. Below is my code...

```
public void SendEmail(string ToMailAddress, string CCMailAddress, string MsgSubject, string MsgBody)
    {
        try
        {
            string FromMailID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMail"].ToString();
            string Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
            string Host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"].ToString();
            string Port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();

            using (MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                objMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(FromMailID);

                string[] toMailAddresses = ToMailAddress.Split(',');
                foreach (string emailAddress in toMailAddresses)
                {
                    objMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
                }

                string[] ccMailAddresses = CCMailAddress.Split(',');
                foreach (string emailAddress in ccMailAddresses)
                {
                    objMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
                }

                objMailMessage.Subject = MsgSubject;
                objMailMessage.Body = MsgBody;
                objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                objMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                objMailMessage.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = Host;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(FromMailID, Password);
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Port);
                smtp.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;

                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                // To be used in case SSL is required...
                //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
                //    delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

                smtp.Send(objMailMessage);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what is wrong here...PLEASE HELP...

Comment: You'll need to talk to whoever manages the SMTP server your using. They are not allowing you to send the email to the recipient you requested.

Comment: I am learning MVC and made a sample application which sends mail. My laptop is all I have. I was running using F5 in VS 2013 and it was working fine. But now when I have uninstall and installed it again, same code is not working. How to configure SMTP Email in IIS 8 and IIS Express of VS 2013. Can you provide steps...